# MuseScore: Easy way to move entire verses of lyrics

Tags: musescore, lyrics

I set a text to music, but I started too low when writing the song text into MuseScore (because there had been lyrics already, which I deleted beforehand as I recall). Now there are three "empty lines", and only then the first verse starts.

Is there a way to move all lyrics three lines up? See picture...

[image: Mis-placed lyrics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MuseScore's lyrics functions are poorly implemented, which makes them very hard to edit or move en masse. As far as I know, there is no way to move these all simultaneously. Your options are to retype them all or move each lyric segment.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is a bit cumbersome, but it'll be okay. I wanted to ask *before* doing it, so that I won't come to know with hindsight there would have been an easier way.

Comment: This is somewhat out of date. MuseScore's lyrics still aren't very good, but they are a lot better than they used to be.

Answer (score 2):

Here are instructions valid as of MuseScore 3.5.0.13199 Revision 43c5553 (Windows 10).

1. Right click on the verse you want to remove, and choose `select` -> `more...`.
2. In the `select` dialog, click the `same subtype` option, then click the `ok` button.
3. Press `delete`.
4. Right-click on the verse to be moved, and repeat step #2.
5. In the `Element Inspector` (press `F8` if not showing), in the `Lyrics` section, decrement the verse number.
6. Admire your haniwork.

---

## Again, but with pictures ...

#### 1) Right click on the verse you want to remove, and choose `select` -> `more...`.

[image: MuseScore menu]

#### 2) In the `select` dialog, click the `same subtype` option, then click the `ok` button.

[image: "Select" menu]

**Your score will look something like this.**

[image: Score with verse selected]

#### 3) Press `delete`.

[image: Score after verse deleted]

#### 4) Right-click on the verse to be moved, and repeat step #2.

5. In the `Element Inspector` (press `F8` if not showing), in the `Lyrics` section, decrement the verse number.

**This section is at the bottom of the Inspector window**

[image: Lyric verse adjustment button]

**Your lyrics move as you make Inspector changes**

[image: Lyrics after adjustment]

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Right Click on the individual words you want to move and then with the Ctrl Key down drag the lyrics up.  I guess the command key would work for Mac users.

Comment: user30337, is this now supported?  If so what version of Musescore supports this?

Answer (score -3):

In Muscore 2 I found a way of moving the entire lyrics in one system: Right click on word in the system you want to move: > Select > More... Now you activate the check boxes "Same subtype" and "same system", then click "OK". Now you are able to move the lyrics up and down in the "Element Inspector" (F8 if not visible) by clicking vertical offset (up/down). (Muscore 2, Linux Mint 21)

Comment: This method is explained in more detail in another answer to this question. Also Musescore 2 is at least five years out of date, the latest is version 4.